# xubuntu 18.04 vs 20.04: same font displayed differently

Tags: xubuntu, 20.04, fonts, xfce

I'm trying xubuntu 20.04 prior to fully migrate from xubuntu 18.04. Almost everything looks fine and running smooth, except my favorite XFCE desktop font's appearance. In 18.04, I modified a gtk-2 theme and use **Arial MT Medium** (opentype) font for desktop icon-label. I know that 20.04 comes with gtk3 theme, and in 20.04 my gtk-2 theme becomes so ugly. So, I translate any possible part of gtk-2 theme into gtk3 and so far so good, except that one, desktop icon-label font.

[image: here is the comparison]

in 18.04, the font looks very good, solid and brightful in white color. While in 20.04, to me, it looks like not being anti-aliased. Can this be fixed? thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks quite OK to me in 20.04. Indeed, some more shadowing and the font appears a bit smaller, but that indeed may be due to GTK3 doing things slightly different. Surely there is antialiasing in both cases.

Comment: agree, but for me this is quite a regression. i've been using ubuntu for years and such (rendering) thing always consistent..

Comment: anyhow, just trying out. only a matter of personal satisfactory. would be happy if this can be fixed. otherwise continue with my best light & stable friend xubuntu 18.04 :)

Comment: You could check whether changing the hinting and aliasing in Ubuntu Tweak does not allow you to get closer to the appearance as in 18.04.

Comment: @vanadium, I've tried that and no effect at all. I believe what you said above regarding gtk3. I think it's ok to do things diffeferently as long as the result is the same. Need time to research this small (personal) annoyance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over a year I left this off. Now, I'm back with a solution.

I simply :

```
1. copy ArialMTStd-Medium.otf font to /usr/share/fonts
2. fc-cache -f -v
3. set XfdesktopIconView.view { font-family: 'Arial MT Std Medium' } in my customized gtk3 theme :)
4. refresh current theme
```

Now my favorite desktop-icon label font is back in Xubuntu 20.04

**edit**:

my bad, forgot to embed the final result

[image]    [image]